# Using self joins sql query

Tags: db2

I have a Table, TEmployee where SequenceId, Date, EmplId, ExtnNumber, FName are the attributes, where SequenceId is unique and there will be multiple entries for same EmplId like

```
1   1/1/2014    55323   8793    Ryan
2   1/2/2014    83723   9898    Roy
3   1/1/2014    88838   8823    Mark
4   1/2/2014    83723   9832    Roy
5   1/3/2014    32323   2223    Tina
6   1/1/2014    55323   8744    Ryan
```

`select * from TEmployee where EmplId in ('55323','83723')` with urlists me the following..

```
1   1/1/2014    55323   8793    Ryan
2   1/2/2014    83723   9898    Roy
4   1/2/2014    83723   9832    Roy
6   1/1/2014    55323   8744    Ryan
```

But, i want to list the latest entry to be displayed.. by latest i mean SequenceId.. only entries 4 & 6..

Any pointers would be of good help. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jimmy Smith beat me to it with a correct answer, but mine is a correlated subselect, so there is no need to repeat the `EMPLID IN ('55323', '83723')` part.

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM TEMPLOYEE AS A 
 WHERE EMPLID IN ('55323', '83723') 
 AND SEQUENCEID = (
     SELECT MAX(SEQUENCEID) 
     FROM TEMPLOYEE AS B 
     WHERE A.EMPLID = B.EMPLID
     )
 WITH UR
```

Answer (score 0):

One method may be via a subquery,

```
select * from TEmployee where EmplId in ('55323', '83723') and SequenceId in (Select Max(SequenceId) where EmplId in ('55323', '83723'))
```